# Share link via Facebook application Android

Tags: android, facebook

In my application i created a FACEBOOK SHARE BUTTON.when the button clicked i want to share a specific link.if phone already got facebook application link should share from that application.how can i do that. can someone please help me out.any comment will highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try share intent

```
Intent sendMailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendMailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Indian Link Radio");
sendMailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your link here"); 
sendMailIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendMailIntent, "Share Using"));
```

Comment: thanks for concern ingsaurabh.i need to open the facebook application and when mail and password is entered it should publish the link on users wall.how can i do that

Comment: im testing on emulator.is that the reason that im opening mail application directly.i mean facebook app is not installed in emulator.if i tested in a facebook installed device ur code should work.im i ri8????

Comment: Test on real device it will show you the list of sharing apps and choose FB from it